# Cannot retrieve attachments with blankspaces in the filename with javamail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, content-type, email-attachments

I have problems when downloading attachments with javamail when they have a blankspace in the file name and no extension.

This is due to the content-type of the BodyPart. For the files `example.pdf` and `example` I have the content-type equal to  `APPLICATION/PDF; name=example.pdf`  and `APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM; name=example`, respectively, while if I have the file `example 2` i have `APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM;`. This makes me impossible to retrieve the file with javamail.

This is very strange to me, anybody knows why? Or some workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "problems downloading attachments" means exactly.  Is there an exception thrown?

If the message is properly formatted, spaces in the filename shouldn't make any difference.

If the message isn't properly formatted (e.g., the "name" parameter isn't quoted when it contains spaces), you may need to set some properties to have JavaMail work around that bug in the sending program.  See the javadocs for the javax.mail.internet package for details.